# PHP not getting the middle letter in a string

Tags: php

So I dont know why i cant get the middle letter of the string. This is the code

```
$length = strlen($upper);
if($length % 2 == 0){
     $middle = $length/2;
     $gitna = substr($upper,$middle-1,$middle);
}else{
     $middle = ($length-1)/2;
     $gitna = substr($upper,$middle-1,$middle);
}
```

The result of the code is

```
$upper = ACESHARDEWARE
$length = 13
$middle = 6
$gitna = ARDEWA
```

I dont know why $gitna results to ARDEWA. I need to get the middle letter of the string and im expecting to get $gitna = "R" but why its giving me 6 letter. Any help?

Comment: read the documentation for `substr`. The third parameter is length and should be 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your substring length should be 1:

```
$length = strlen($upper);
if ($length % 2 == 0) {
     $middle = $length/2;
     $gitna = substr($upper, $middle, 1);
} else {
     $middle = ($length-1)/2;
     $gitna = substr($upper, $middle, 1);
}
```

The third parameter of the `substr` function is the length, so if you just want a single character this needs to be `1` ([full documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)).

Comment: Wow thanks it works! and correction in my code the $middle-1 should be $middle